# Google Scripts copyto issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get a row with a certain range to copy into the row after text ends. I had it working a few days ago, but cannot figure out where I am going wrong right now.

So far I have:

```
    function getNextRow();
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow()+1;
    }

    function test() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var range = ss.getRange('a4:e4')
    var data = range.getValues();
    var nextrow = getNextRow();
    ss.getRange(nextrow).setValues(data);
    }
```

I have attempted the copyto, but cannot seem to figure it out again from the google developer's page. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you never specify the *sheet* you are working with. Which sheet of the spreadsheet should this script act on? Use `getActiveSheet` to pick the active one, or `getSheetByName` to pick a particular sheet.

Also, your function `getNextRow` returns an integer, which is the number of the first row that's below all the data. So far so good. But then you call `ss.getRange(nextrow)` where nextrow is that integer... not good. This isn't one of the [acceptable ways](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) of using this method: it needs either A1 notation, or (row, column) pair of integers for a single cell, or (row, column, number of rows, number of columns) quadruple for a range of more than one cell. Which is what you have, so use

```
ss.getRange(nextrow, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

This says: starting in the row `nextrow`, column 1 (meaning A), select the range of same size as `data`. The pair `data.length, data[0].length` is how one gets the height and width of `data` array.

That said, there is an easier way to achieve what you want, using [`appendRow`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) method. Here's a function that would replace all of your code:

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('a4:e4')
  var data = range.getValues();
  sheet.appendRow(data[0]); 
}
```

This appends the content of A4:E4 in the active sheet to the bottom of the same sheet. The method `appendRow` takes a one-dimensional array, hence `data[0]` and not just `data` (which is two-dimensional).